# How to split string containing comma using span tag

Tags: html, jquery, css, html-table

There is a string containing tags separated by comma:

```
<div class="article" id="1">
    <span class="tags">Dog, Cat, Bird, Pig</span>
</div>
      
<div class="article" id="2">
    <span class="tags">Asia, Africa, Australia, Europe</span>
</div>
...
```

I would like to wrap each item using span tag within the tags class so that each of them can be individually styled like this

```
<span class="tags"><span>Dog</span><span>Cat</span>...</span>
```

Comment: Why do you need that? Strange task. What you need to achieve in real?

Comment: Where do you get the string ("Dog, Cat, Bird....") from? Is this part of a PHP script `echo`ing articles wrapped in `div`s one by one?

Comment: @nhee this string is just a sample code for this example. I'm using mongodb for storing and retrieving data using meteor framework.

Comment: Ok, let me rephrase. When retrieving the tags from the database, can you do something like `echo '<span>' . str_replace(', ','</span><span>',$string) . '</span>';`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.tags').html($('.tags').html().split(', ').map(function(el) {return '<span>' + el + '</span>'}))
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zcmte9hg/)