# Comma separated tags in template variable

Tags: modx, modx-evolution

I have a template variable called TAGS... the input is as follows: "alpha,beta,gamma,delta". So technically thats one tag.
How to separate the individual tags inside this one tag so I can apply HTML anc CSS code to them.
For example, that "alpha" has `border:1px solid black`, and for "gamma" the same CSS style. If I apply this example CSS code on my TV TAGS, then the whole block of "alpha,beta,gamma,delta" gets the border and not the individual tags. How to do this for EVO 1.1.?

Comment: Theres some extensions that allow this in Revo (eg: MigX) but not sure if this is possible in Evo.

However, you could pull this off with JQuery: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29876699/how-to-split-string-containing-comma-using-span-tag

Comment: @MeltingDog - the jQuery solution is a good alternative, thanks!